# Is there Type Migration for Kotlin in Intellij?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I come across to refactor a piece of code in Kotlin, and I press `Ctr+Shift+F6` to [migrate its type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html). I know it works perfectly in Java, but it doesn't work in Kotlin.

1. Do you know alternatives to do such operations automatically in Kotlin?
2. Is there any specific reason that Intellij doesn't have Type Migration for Kotlin?

Comment: This refactoring is not yet implemented for Kotlin, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21720 for updates.